# Weird PHP date incrementation

Tags: php, date, timezone, timestamp

I was trying to do a loop to find the weekends between two dates and something was really damn strange.

I have to following code which in my opinion should be working fine.

```
$weekends = array();
// yyyy-mm-dd
$firstWeekend = '2015-09-04';
$lastWeekend = '2015-12-25';
$firstWeekendTime = strtotime($firstWeekend);
$lastWeekendTime = strtotime($lastWeekend);

$totalWeekends = 0;
for ($i = $firstWeekendTime; $i <= $lastWeekendTime; $i += (7 * 86400)) {
  $totalWeekends++;
  $weekends[date('Y-m-d', $i)] = array(
    date('Y-m-d', $i),
    date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m-d', $i) . '+ 2 days'))
  );
}
```

Eg. output:

```
[2015-10-16] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-10-16
        [1] => 2015-10-18
    )

[2015-10-23] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-10-23
        [1] => 2015-10-25
    )

[2015-10-29] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-10-29
        [1] => 2015-10-31
    )

[2015-11-05] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-11-05
        [1] => 2015-11-07
    )
```

But this is not correct cause the next weekend after 2015-10-23 is 2015-10-30.
So the output should be this:

```
[2015-10-16] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-10-16
        [1] => 2015-10-18
    )

[2015-10-23] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-10-23
        [1] => 2015-10-25
    )

[2015-10-30] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-10-30
        [1] => 2015-11-01
    )

[2015-11-05] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-11-05
        [1] => 2015-11-07
    )
```

I finally made it work by putting a default timezone and without chaning anything else, it worked.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Can someone understand why does this incrementation fail without the timezone?
And the weirdest thing is that it only fails around ~2015-10-25

I don't want other options to find the weekend... i just want to understand why it acts like this.

Thank you.

Comment: You do realise that not every day has 86400 seconds, especially in months where there's a daylight savings change.... like October

Comment: @MarkBaker Now i realize that I've never thought about that. Thank you

Comment: Using DateTime objects, with DateInterval and DatePeriod is a lot easier to handle things like this, because it's timezone and transition aware

Comment: Or just set the time zone to `"Etc/UTC"`

Answer (score 0):

Just you have to change the for loop condition with increment value like this

```
for ($i = $firstWeekendTime; $i <= $lastWeekendTime; $i = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m-d', $i) . '+ 7 days'))))
```

instead of

```
for ($i = $firstWeekendTime; $i <= $lastWeekendTime; $i += (7 * 86400))
```